# Why is my bundle a null object reference?

Tags: java, android

I am building an app where the user creates a listView and then the user is able to click on one of the listViews and a dialog will pop up and let the user edit that listView that they clicked on. 
Here is my EditCityFragment where once the user clicks on the listView this fragment is called. also I am using an arraylist to store my data, I have figured out how to add a city.

```
 static AddCityFragment newInstance(City city){
        AddCityFragment fragment = new AddCityFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("city", city);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.add_city_fragment_layout, null);
        AddCityFragment.newInstance(savedInstanceState);
        cityName = view.findViewById(R.id.city_name_editText);
        provinceName = view.findViewById(R.id.province_editText);

        city = (City) getArguments().getSerializable("city");
        String s = city.getCityName();
        String p = city.getProvinceName();
        cityName.setText(s);
        provinceName.setText(p);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        return builder
                .setView(view)
                .setTitle("Edit City")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        String city = cityName.getText().toString();
                        String province = provinceName.getText().toString();
                        listener.onOkPressed(new City(city, province));

                    }}).create();
    }


}
```

here is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simpleparadox.listycity, PID: 13929
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.simpleparadox.listycity.EditCityFragment.onCreateDialog(EditCityFragment.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:330)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1308)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: AddCityFragment.newInstance(savedInstanceState);
remove this line in onCreateDialog() in AddCityFRagment

and if have this line in EditCityFragment then remove from there as well.

Comment: @KishanMaurya doing that still crashes the app

Comment: If possible, Can you share the link?